# Entity Relationship - CodeFirst - Multiple Relationships

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to create the following object for my DB (CodeFirst),
And i have the following problem:

when i try to add new one or many object to a new srevice provider slots (as follows:)

```
 ServiceProviderSlots slot = new ServiceProviderSlots();

        slot.ServiceProviderID = 1;
        slot.SlotServices.Add(new ServiceProviderServices() { ServiceProviderServiceID = 1 });

        ctx.ServiceProviderSlots.Add(slot);
```

I get an error, because i'm not creating a new object, and i'm missing foreign keys, but i wish to use data which already exists on that table.

**ERROR:**

```
{"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.ServiceProviderServices_dbo.ServiceProviders_ServiceProviderID\". The conflict occurred in database \"qunadodb\", table \"dbo.ServiceProviders\", column 'ServiceProviderID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

Maybe it's related to this?

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
```

Which i used becuase i couldn't create the db otherwise, i had another error.

See below structure:

```
public class BusinessCategories
{

    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }        
}



public class BusinessTypes
{
    [Key]
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual BusinessCategories Categories { get; set; }         
}

public class ServiceProviders
{

    [Key]
    public int ServiceProviderID { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Int32 TypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual BusinessTypes Type { get; set; }

}

public class ServiceProviderServices
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ServiceProviderServiceID { get; set; }

    public String Price { get; set; }

    public Int32 ServiceProviderID { get; set; }
    public virtual ServiceProviders ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public Int32 SubServiceID { get; set; }
    public virtual SubServices SubService { get; set; }

}


public class ServiceProviderSlots
{
    public ServiceProviderSlots()
    {
        SlotServices = new List<ServiceProviderServices>();

    }
    [Key]
    public Int32 SlotID { get; set; }


    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Int32 ServiceProviderID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ServiceProviderID")]
    public virtual ServiceProviders ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ServiceProviderServices> SlotServices { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this message means that you probably yet have a ServiceProvider with Id = 1 in the database.

in this cas you have to attach the entity to the context.

Comment: I wanted a many to many relationship, i solved it by creating a sub table.